# As funções autoload do php, fazem um objeto disponível a qualquer parte do site numa mesma sessão, mesmo em sub diretórios diferentes?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, php-autoload

Eu tenho a intenção de deixar o meu código mais limpo e por isso evitar usar `include` ou `include_once` todo início de página. Não gostaria de usar frameworks que já fazem esse trabalho como laravel por exemplo. Quero criar a função "from the scratch".

Entáo temos aqui 2 maneiras distintas de usar funções autoload para chamar uma classe quando se tenta instanciar um objeto.

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {              
    include './class/'.$class_name . '.php';
});

================== ou ========================

function __autoload($className) {
    $className = str_replace("..","", $className);
    require_once ("./class/$className.php");
}
```

Eu estou usando a função na página `index.php`. 
A minha dúvida é se existe alguma restrinção de subnível para ela funcionar. Ou seja, se uma classe for chamada num arquivo `file.php ($myObj=new myclass();)` dentro do diretório `dir1/dir2/dir3/file.php` ela continuaria reconhecendo o caminho até `root/class/myclass.php`? Existe algum limite ?

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação de como usar, também gostaria de saber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo que você usa o autoload no composer, que além de leve ele trabalha bem com namespaces.

Mas respondendo sua pergunta, quando você concatena o caminho do arquivo, coloca na frente a função `dirname(__FILE__)` que retornará a pasta do autoload. A partir dessa pasta é só ir a pasta das classes.

Comment: Como eu disse, estou querendo fazer algo desde o zero. Não queria usar nem Laravael nem Composer. Então quer dizer que se eu declarar a função na página index.php, passar o caminho do diretório das classes em relação ao index.php e chamar uma classe 2 ou 3 niveis abaixo do index ela não funcionaria?

Comment: Sim vai funcionar, porque ele pega a pasta do arquivo que tem a função `dirname(__FILE__)`.
Independente de onde começou a ser executado.